# How to do continuous real life tracking of car in android like UBER?

Tags: android, geolocation, tracking, gsm, google-geocoding-api

How to get current location continuously in android, like an **UBER** application, in which the car's location is continuously tracked.

**Thanks in advance**..

Comment: firebase geofire and firebase real time database is what you need

Comment: send current location to your server every x seconds, that's it.

Comment: Might want to use a spelling checker next time....

Answer (score 2):

Use firebase to store the car location data and retrieve that data to show in a map. Or you may consider looking into [this](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java).

Answer (score 0):

Here at [HyperTrack](http://hypertrack.com) (disclaimer: I work here) we built a plug-and-play location-tracking API which is the fastest way to get location data in your application. From what I understand of your question, it would work perfectly, giving you what you would need to get started for free. Once you plug in the SDK (~1m to do) and rebuild your application you'll immediately start seeing location tracking in the free web dashboard.

Comment: Thanks [Jerdog](http://stackoverflow.com/users/561377/jerdog) for getting precious help..
really Helpfull...

Comment: @AhsanSaeed you certainly can. You can put the SDK into your app and interact with it in many different ways by following our documentation (http://docs.hypertrack.com). As to the Dashboard you can add a widget into your existing view or use our free Dashboard view.